# Is there any solution to the error while loading SIVP module to scilab

Tags: scilab

SIVP - Scilab Image and Video Processing Toolbox
    Load macros
atomsLoad: An error occurred while loading 'SIVP-0.5.3.2':
    lib: Old binary lib detected. Please recompile it for Scilab 6.

help me get out of this problem

Answer (score 0):

sivp has not been ported to scilab 6. If you want to do some image processing you should rather use [IPCV atoms module](https://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/IPCV).

Comment: Does it support all the operations that SIVP does

Comment: Yes. Moreover, unlike SIVP, it is actively maintained by the author (Tan Chin Luh).